# Maven JSF version

Tags: jsf, maven, repository

In Eclipse I try to add dependencies for JSF (mojarra) 2.0.
But Maven doesn't find. Only version 1.2
Is it possible download with Maven or need manually?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Guide to Coping with Sun JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-coping-with-sun-jars.html):

> Unfortunately most of these artifacts fall under Sun's Binary License which disallows us from distributing them from Ibiblio.

Mojarra 2.x is in the [java.net](http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/faces/) repository:

```xml
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

*Since you mention Mojarra specifically, I guess you want that specific version. But for anyone finding this page on Google...*

Alternatively, the Apache MyFaces implementation of JSF is available from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) under the `org.apache.myfaces.core` groupId:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

If all you want is a compile-time dependency on the public 2.0 API, you can use the Java EE 6 API in the provided scope:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Maven page on the Mojarra site](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html) explains how to add their repository to maven so that you can get the latest version of the dependency.